# Flash error on submitted page when there are errors from body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser, express-handlebars

I have a create page which input fields and I have configured the body-parser with length restriction. When I submit the create form body-parse fails the request for length limitation which is actually right. My question is how do I flash the error message from error handler without refreshing/redirecting.

From default error handler page I tried to flash that didn't work.
I wanted flash message on the same page (I need the old data from the form to be intact).

```
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err && err.type == 'entity.too.large' ) {
        req.flash('danger', 'Something unexpected happened!');
    } else {
        next()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ιf you want to display error messages during submitting  forms without refreshing or redirecting, you have to make AJAX requests. You have many choices (fetch api, axios, jquery AJAX ...). Then, depending the result of your controller( error or success) you can display the message you want.